# How to use a seq_file in Linux kernel modules?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel

Hello all I'm new to Linux and wondering how to use a Linux sequence file in a module to traverse kernel objects.

What I know is I can use the command:

```
 cat /proc/kallsyms
```

to view the available symbols and from what I've read on google, the symbols in the list that have a 'D' or 'd' are pointers to data structures.

Though I know the basics of how to create a module, the examples on the internet on how to use seq operations are not uniform and I'm getting a little confused.

If someone knows of any good doco that will help me understand how to create a seq file to traverse kernel objects and could post a link (or a quick example), I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 4):

**Minimal runnable example**

The kernel docs contain an example under [Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.9/Documentation/filesystems/seq_file.txt), but here is a runnable version of that with loop termination.

This example is behaves just like a file that contains:

```
0
1
2
```

However, we only store a single integer in memory
and calculate the file on the fly in an iterator fashion.

The file works for both `read` and `lseek` system calls, but there is no `write` system call equivalent:
[How to implement a writable proc file by using seq_file in a driver module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710517/how-to-implement-a-writable-proc-file-by-using-seq-file-in-a-driver-module)

Play around with the file with `cat` and `dd skip=` for the seeks.

```c
#include <asm/uaccess.h> /* copy_from_user, copy_to_user */
#include <linux/debugfs.h>
#include <linux/errno.h> /* EFAULT */
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h> /* pr_info */
#include <linux/seq_file.h> /* seq_read, seq_lseek, single_release */
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <uapi/linux/stat.h> /* S_IRUSR */

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int max = 2;
module_param(max, int, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

static struct dentry *debugfs_file;

/* Called at the beginning of every read.
 *
 * The return value is passsed to the first show.
 * It normally represents the current position of the iterator.
 * It could be any struct, but we use just a single integer here.
 *
 * NULL return means stop should be called next, and so the read will be empty..
 * This happens for example for an ftell that goes beyond the file size.
 */
static void *start(struct seq_file *s, loff_t *pos)
{
    loff_t *spos;

    pr_info("start pos = %llx\n", (unsigned long long)*pos);
    spos = kmalloc(sizeof(loff_t), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!spos || *pos >= max)
        return NULL;
    *spos = *pos;
    return spos;
}

/* The return value is passed to next show.
 * If NULL, stop is called next instead of show, and read ends.
 *
 * Can get called multiple times, until enough data is returned for the read.
 */
static void *next(struct seq_file *s, void *v, loff_t *pos)
{
    loff_t *spos;

    spos = v;
    pr_info("next pos = %llx\n", (unsigned long long)*pos);
    if (*pos >= max)
        return NULL;
    *pos = ++*spos;
    return spos;
}

/* Called at the end of every read. */
static void stop(struct seq_file *s, void *v)
{
    pr_info("stop\n");
    kfree(v);
}

/* Return 0 means success, SEQ_SKIP ignores previous prints, negative for error. */
static int show(struct seq_file *s, void *v)
{
    loff_t *spos;

    spos = v;
    pr_info("show pos = %llx\n", (unsigned long long)*spos);
    seq_printf(s, "%llx\n", (long long unsigned)*spos);
    return 0;
}

static struct seq_operations my_seq_ops = {
    .next  = next,
    .show  = show,
    .start = start,
    .stop  = stop,
};

static int open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    pr_info("open\n");
    return seq_open(file, &my_seq_ops);
}

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner   = THIS_MODULE,
    .llseek  = seq_lseek,
    .open    = open,
    .read    = seq_read,
    .release = seq_release
};

static int myinit(void)
{
    debugfs_file = debugfs_create_file(
        "lkmc_seq_file", S_IRUSR, NULL, NULL, &fops);
    if (debugfs_file) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -EINVAL;
    }
}

static void myexit(void)
{
    debugfs_remove(debugfs_file);
}

module_init(myinit)
module_exit(myexit)
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/f82c058eb676b9b94a4064dd9cde2c5978d9cdcc/kernel_module/seq_file.c).

Note how the seq_file API makes it much easier to write the `read` file operation.

**`single_open`**

If you have the entire read output upfront, `single_open` is an even more convenient version of seq_file.

This example behaves like a file that contains:

```
ab
cd
```

Code:

```c
#include <asm/uaccess.h> /* copy_from_user, copy_to_user */
#include <linux/debugfs.h>
#include <linux/errno.h> /* EFAULT */
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h> /* pr_info */
#include <linux/seq_file.h> /* seq_read, seq_lseek, single_release */
#include <uapi/linux/stat.h> /* S_IRUSR */

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static struct dentry *debugfs_file;

static int show(struct seq_file *m, void *v)
{
    seq_printf(m, "ab\ncd\n");
    return 0;
}

static int open(struct inode *inode, struct  file *file)
{
    return single_open(file, show, NULL);
}

static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .llseek = seq_lseek,
    .open = open,
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = seq_read,
    .release = single_release,
};

static int myinit(void)
{
    debugfs_file = debugfs_create_file(
        "lkmc_seq_file_single", S_IRUSR, NULL, NULL, &fops);
    if (debugfs_file) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -EINVAL;
    }
}

static void myexit(void)
{
    debugfs_remove(debugfs_file);
}

module_init(myinit)
module_exit(myexit)
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/f82c058eb676b9b94a4064dd9cde2c5978d9cdcc/kernel_module/seq_file_single.c).

Tested on Linux 4.9.6.

It appears that starting from Linux 5, there was a backwards incompatible change that requires you to implement `seq_file` a bit differently, I think this talks about it: [seq_file not working properly after next returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570242/seq-file-not-working-properly-after-next-returns-null) and it appears that if you don't update this you get a warning:

```
seq_file: buggy .next function next [module-name] did not update position index
```

Comment: Note that you need to have the `debugfs` file-system mounted on your system.

Comment: Also, `seq_file: buggy .next function next [module-name] did not update position index`.

Comment: @Roi I suspect this is an incompatibility between Linux 4 and 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570242/seq-file-not-working-properly-after-next-returns-null Let me know if you confirm.

Comment: It does seem to be the issue, although I haven't tried the fix.