# seq_file not working properly after next returns NULL

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

What is wrong with this code (I guess with regard to compatibility with different kernel versions)?

```c
#define BUFFER_SIZE 2048
#define BUFFER_STEP 128

static char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 }; // this is filled with repeating letters a-z in module init

static void* seqf_ex_start (struct seq_file* m, loff_t* pos)
{
    if (*pos >= BUFFER_SIZE) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return buffer + *pos;
}

static void* seqf_ex_next (struct seq_file* m, void* v, loff_t* pos)
{
    *pos += BUFFER_STEP;

    if (*pos >= BUFFER_SIZE) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return buffer + *pos;
}

static int seqf_ex_show (struct seq_file* m, void* v)
{
    seq_printf(m, "%.*s\n", BUFFER_STEP, (char*)v);

    return 0;
}
```

When running the kernel module in qemuarm (kernel `v5.0.19`), I get the correct output:

```
$ cat /proc/seqf-ex | awk '{ print "line" OFS NR ":" OFS length($0) }'
line 1: 128
line 2: 128
line 3: 128
line 4: 128
line 5: 128
line 6: 128
line 7: 128
line 8: 128
line 9: 128
line 10: 128
line 11: 128
line 12: 128
line 13: 128
line 14: 128
line 15: 128
line 16: 128
```

But when running on kernel `v4.15.0`, I get this:

```
$ cat /proc/seqf-ex | awk '{ print "line" OFS NR ":" OFS length($0) }'
line 1: 128
line 2: 128
line 3: 128
line 4: 128
line 5: 128
line 6: 128
line 7: 128
line 8: 128
line 9: 128
line 10: 128
line 11: 128
line 12: 128
line 13: 128
line 14: 128
line 15: 128
line 16: 128
line 17: 127
line 18: 126
line 19: 125
line 20: 124
line 21: 123
line 22: 122
line 23: 121
line 24: 120
line 25: 119
line 26: 118
line 27: 117
line 28: 116
line 29: 115
line 30: 114
line 31: 113
line 32: 112
line 33: 111
line 34: 110
line 35: 109
line 36: 108
line 37: 107
line 38: 106
line 39: 105
line 40: 104
line 41: 103
line 42: 102
line 43: 101
line 44: 100
line 45: 99
line 46: 98
line 47: 97
line 48: 96
line 49: 95
line 50: 94
line 51: 93
line 52: 92
line 53: 91
line 54: 90
line 55: 89
line 56: 88
line 57: 87
line 58: 86
line 59: 85
line 60: 84
line 61: 83
line 62: 82
line 63: 81
line 64: 80
line 65: 79
line 66: 78
line 67: 77
line 68: 76
line 69: 75
line 70: 74
line 71: 73
line 72: 72
line 73: 71
line 74: 70
line 75: 69
line 76: 68
line 77: 67
line 78: 66
line 79: 65
line 80: 64
line 81: 63
line 82: 62
line 83: 61
line 84: 60
line 85: 59
line 86: 58
line 87: 57
line 88: 56
line 89: 55
line 90: 54
line 91: 53
line 92: 52
line 93: 51
line 94: 50
line 95: 49
line 96: 48
line 97: 47
line 98: 46
line 99: 45
line 100: 44
line 101: 43
line 102: 42
line 103: 41
line 104: 40
line 105: 39
line 106: 38
line 107: 37
line 108: 36
line 109: 35
line 110: 34
line 111: 33
line 112: 32
line 113: 31
line 114: 30
line 115: 29
line 116: 28
line 117: 27
line 118: 26
line 119: 25
line 120: 24
line 121: 23
line 122: 22
line 123: 21
line 124: 20
line 125: 19
line 126: 18
line 127: 17
line 128: 16
line 129: 15
line 130: 14
line 131: 13
line 132: 12
line 133: 11
line 134: 10
line 135: 9
line 136: 8
line 137: 7
line 138: 6
line 139: 5
line 140: 4
line 141: 3
line 142: 2
line 143: 1
```

It seems that `seqf_start` function is called repeatedly after the `seqf_next` returns `NULL`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe this one helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/25399112/1741542

Comment: I have seen this, but it's not really related to my question.

Comment: "It seems that `seqf_start` function is called repeatedly after the `seqf_next` returns NULL." - `.start` function is called **at least once** after `.next` returns NULL. In that case you need to return NULL from that `start` call to tell `cat` command that the file is really ends. Add `printk` statements into your `.start` function and see what **actually happens** and what your `.start` function **actually returns**.

Comment: Hint: You code works correctly only when `*pos` value is **divisible by** `BUFFER_STEP`. You expect this is always true (well, I would expect that too), as the only place you update the `*pos` is `seqf_ex_next` function, which increments `*pos` by `BUFFER_STEP`. However, [in Linux kernel 4.15](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.18/source/fs/seq_file.c) there are places where `*pos` is incremented just by 1. Probably, you hit one of this place. Just add `printk` into your `seqf_ex_start` and `seqf_ex_next` functions for check **actual** value of `*pos`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hi, thanks! That is sort of behaviour I noticed and I managed to solve it by changing the check in the start function; checking if *pos + BUFFER_STEP is greater than BUFFER_SIZE instead of just *pos seems to fix it. I wondered however if there was something I was missing or doing wrong with regard to the API, because on kernel 5 it works exactly as I would expect it. Thanks

Comment: Changing comparision to `*pos + BUFFER_STEP > BUFFER_SIZE` only hides your real problem: your `seqf_ex_show` function isn't ready to non-divisible values of `*pos`. So, would you use commands other than `cat` or `awk` for read your file, you would again face with incorrect behavior. See my answer for better fix of your code.

Comment: BTW, `cat <file> | awk <script>` is an example of [Useless Use of cat, UUOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat). Instead, use `awk -f <script> <file>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some **incompatibility** between Linux kernel 4.x and 5.x versions about handling `*pos` argument passed to `seq_file` callback functions.

Linux kernel 5.x only sets `*pos` to 0 and leave other modifications to the `seq_file` callbacks (`.start` and `.next` functions in `struct seq_operations`).

However, in Linux kernel 4.x `*pos` can be incremented by 1 **outside of your callbacks**. This is done if the last `.show` call produces **exactly** number of bytes needed to fulfill request of `read` syscall.

Because your code is ready only to `*pos` values which are divisible by `BUFFER_STEP`, it works incorrectly when `*pos` is incremented outside of your functions, so it is divisible by `BUFFER_STEP` no longer.

---

I don't know whether behavior of Linux 4.x is correct, but if you want your code to work with such behavior, you need to prepare to all values of `*pos`, not only to ones produced by your code.

Simple fix of your code would be interpret `*pos` as a **chunk index** instead of a *byte index*:

```
static void* seqf_ex_start (struct seq_file* m, loff_t* pos)
{
    if (*pos >= (BUFFER_SIZE/BUFFER_STEP)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return buffer + (*pos * BUFFER_STEP);
}

static void* seqf_ex_next (struct seq_file* m, void* v, loff_t* pos)
{
    *pos += 1;

    if (*pos >= (BUFFER_SIZE/BUFFER_STEP)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    return buffer + (*pos * BUFFER_STEP);
}

static int seqf_ex_show (struct seq_file* m, void* v)
{
    seq_printf(m, "%.*s\n", BUFFER_STEP, (char*)v);

    return 0;
}
```

Such a way your code will work with **all values** of `*pos`. (Those which are too high would be cut off by checks `if (*pos >= (BUFFER_SIZE/BUFFER_STEP))`). And increment of `*pos` by 1 performed outside of your code is equivalent to calling your `.next` callback.